# Calling a method in a separate class

Tags: java, object, methods

First, I have

```
if (playerCommand.startsWith("yell")) {
            Yell();  

    }
```

In a class titled "commands.java" This class handles input commands. I want to have the method for this specific command in a class located elsewhere, the code is

```
public class Yell {
/*
 * The minimum rights required to use the yell channel
 */
private final static int MINIMUM_RIGHTS_REQUIREMENT = 0;

/*
 * Time in seconds between the client must wait between submitting yells
 */
private final static int SECONDS_BETWEEN_SUBMITION = 3;

/*
 * Minimum player rights at which restrictions are ignored
 */
private final static int BYPASS_LIMITATION_RIGHTS = 6;


/*
 * An enumeration containing format data
 */
static enum yellData {
    /* Rights, Color, Title */
    PLAYER(0,"255","Player"),
    SPECIAL(1,"16730502","Special"),
    VETERAN(2,"13132800","Veteran"),
    DONATOR(3,"42575","Donator"),
    SUPER_DONATOR(4,"3327","Super Donator"),
    EXTREME_DONATOR(5,"1800639","Extreme Donator"),
    TRIAL_MODERATOR(6, "11809016", "Trial Mod"),
    MODERATOR(7, "562688", "Mod"),
    ADMIN(8, "15604003", "Admin"),
    HEAD_ADMIN(9, "16274188", "Head Admin"),
    CO_OWNER(10, "13369344", "Co-Owner"),
    OWNER(11, "13369344", "Owner");

    private int rights;
    private String color, title;

    private yellData(int rights, String color, String title) {
        this.rights = rights;
        this.color = color;
        this.title = title; 
    }

    private int getRights() {
        return rights;
    }
    private String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    private String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}

public static void sendYellMessage(final Client c, String text) {
    /* Restrictions - Do not apply to rights under Bypass Limitation Rights */
    if (c.playerRights <= BYPASS_LIMITATION_RIGHTS) {
        if (Connection.isMuted(c)) {
            c.sendMessage("You are muted.");
            return;
        }
        if (c.playerRights < MINIMUM_RIGHTS_REQUIREMENT) {
            c.sendMessage("You do not have permission to use the yell channel.");
            return; 
        }
        if (c.playerCanYell == false) {
            c.sendMessage("Please wait a few seconds between yells.");
            return;
        }

        /* Formatting string prevention */
        String[] forbidden = {"<col", "<shad", "<img", "<str", "<tran", "tradereq", "duelreq", "clanreq", "chalreq", "@str@", "@"}; 
        for (int i = 0; i < forbidden.length; i++) {
            if (text.substring(1).contains(forbidden[i])) {
                c.sendMessage("Your submission contains illegal phrases or characters.");
                System.out.println(formatPlayerName(c.playerName)+" is attempting to use illegal phrases in yell chat.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Generates the yell message */
    String toSend = null;
    for (final yellData rank : yellData.values()) {
        if (c.playerRights == rank.getRights()) {
            String prefix = "[<col="+rank.getColor()+">"+rank.getTitle()+"</col>"+"]";
            String name = "<col=255>"+formatPlayerName(c.playerName)+"</col>";
            String message = formatChat(text.replaceAll("/", ""));
            toSend = prefix+" "+name+": "+message;
        }
    }

    /* Send the message to all online players */
    for (int j = 0; j < PlayerHandler.players.length; j++) {
        if (PlayerHandler.players[j] != null) {
            Client op = (Client) PlayerHandler.players[j];
            op.sendMessage(toSend);
        }
    }

    /* Prevent the client from flooding */
    c.playerCanYell = false;
    EventManager.getSingleton().addEvent(new Event() {

        @Override
        public void execute(EventContainer e) {
            c.playerCanYell = true;
            e.stop();
        }
    }, SECONDS_BETWEEN_SUBMITION * 1000 );

    /* Truncate data after use to save memory */
    toSend = null;
}

/*
 * Capitalizes the first letter between spaces
 * Used to properly format character names
 */
private static String formatPlayerName (String in) {
    final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(in.length());
    String[] words = in.split("\\s");
    for(byte b=0,l=(byte) words.length;b<l;++b) {
      if(b>0) output.append(" ");      
      output.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[b].charAt(0)))
            .append(words[b].substring(1));
    }
    return output.toString();
}

/*
 * Capitalizes the first letter and does not disturb
 * the rest of the sentence capitalizations
 */
private static String formatChat (String in) {
    return in.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + in.substring(1);
}
```

How would I call the class "Yell.java" in the Commands.java file? I have yell in commands declared as an object with

```
Yell = new Yell();
```

Comment: here you have to provide the Valid name to Object of Yell class. same like i have mentioned in my answer. accept it if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

By using reference of created object

```
Yell yellObject = new Yell(); 
yellObject.methodName(); // Use appropriate methodName
```

`new Yell()` creates object which accessed by reference variable, the same will be used to invoke method on created object. Here `yellObject` is reference to created object.

Comment: <identifier> expected 

yellObject.methodName();
                     ^

Comment: @user2257868: Use your methodName. I gave it as a example

Answer (score 1):

use
`Yell yell = new Yell();`  // it will create a object of your Yell class.
And 
`yell.method();`           // this will call methods from Yell class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yell y = new Yell();

y.methodCommand();
```

If method in Commands.java class is static you can directly call it by class name:Like

```
Yell.methodName():
```